# How to build a json object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, json

Right now in my thread controller I have the following

```
def thread
  @thread = Thread.find(params[:id])
  ....
  render :json => {"success" => 1}, :content_type => 'application/json'
end
```

What I'd like to do is build the json response to include @thread, but only some params so it's something like this:

```
{"success" => 1, "thread" => {"id": 1, "title": "hello world"}
```

Any idea how I can build this json object in the rails controller? Goal being to not include all the thread fields and to include success which is not a thread field?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use the model's `as_json` function.

```
render :json => {"success" => 1, :thread => @thread.as_json(:only => [:my, :wanted, :attributes]) }
```

as_json includes a large number of options to help you build a hash ready for JSON encoding including `only`, and `except` which will include all attributes on the model apart from the ones listed. `methods` which will add other methods available on the object and `include` to add associations (belongs_to, has_one, has_many etc) into the hash.

For more info examples see the as_json documentation at: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
  render :json => {"success" => 1, "thread" => { "id" => @thread.id, "title" => @thread.title } }, :content_type => 'application/json'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
render :json => {"success" => 1, "thread" => @thread.attributes.select{ |k, v| ["id", "title"].include? k }}
```